# Find exit code for executing a cmd command through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am using a silent installation command to install software. I am running this command from PowerShell 3.0.

```
$silentInstall = C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Setup-2.0.exe exe /s /v"EULAACCEPTED=\"Yes\" /l*v c:\install.log /qn"

Invoke-Expression $silentInstall
```

This runs the command which installs the software, but it does not wait for it to complete and goes ahead with the next lines of code. I want to have control over the installation so that I would know if it's completed or not.

How do I get an error code for the [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6) cmdlet so that I can get to know if the cmd executed successfully or not?

Comment: Chapter and verse on running external commands: http://edgylogic.com/blog/powershell-and-external-commands-done-right/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're running an MSI installer. When running from the console, control is immediately returned while MSI forks a new process to run the installer. There is no way to change this behavior.

What you'll probably need to do is use `Get-Process` to find a process named `msiexec`, and wait for it to finish. There is always an `msiexec` process running, which handles starting new installers, so you'll need to find the `msiexec` process that started after your install began.

```
$msiexecd = Get-Process -Name 'msiexec'
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Setup-2.0.exe exe `
                                       /s `
                                       /v"EULAACCEPTED=\"Yes\" /l*v c:\install.log /qn"
$myMsi = Get-Process -Name 'msiexec' | 
             Where-Object { $_.Id -ne $msiexecd.Id }
$myMsi.WaitForExit()
Write-Verbose $myMsi.ExitCode
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helps. This is what I was looking for. I could find the msiexec process running but I could not figure out how to get the exit code (to find if the installation is successful or not.)

Answer (score 24):

It depends on how the EXE file runs - sometimes it will kick off a separate process and return immediately, and in such cases this usually works -

```
$p = Start-Process -FilePath <path> -ArgumentList <args> -Wait -NoNewWindow -PassThru
$p.ExitCode
```

Otherwise this usually works -

```
& <path> <args>
$LASTEXITCODE
```

Or sometimes this -

```
& cmd.exe /c <path> <args>
$LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: $LASTEXITCODE is what I needed when not going with the `Start-Process` approach.

Comment: +1 for the cmd.exe /c trick - this is the only thing that worked to get the exit code when running VC++ installer.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to use Invoke-Expression:

```
& C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Setup-2.0.exe /s /vEULAACCEPTED=Yes /l*v C:\install.log /qn
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works out of the box, including retrieving the error code by `$?`.

Comment: Note that some setup.exe files (e.g. the ones generated by Inno Setup) return immediately when run with `&`. I had to use `Start-Process -Wait -PassThru` for some reason...