# How to Fail Build on NUnitTest Fail using Powershell

Tags: powershell, build, nunit

I am running all the unittest.dll using NUnitConsole3 test runner and it generates xml TestResult report after successful build.How will i make the build fail if any of the unit test fails?

Given below is the script to run Unit test

```
$SourceDir = "C:\Users\M1036083\Source\Repos\TestSitecoreProject"


$OutDir = "C:\Builds\2\Demo\bin"



## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Set Nunit Tool path 
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$nunit = "$SourceDir\NUnit.Console-3.6.1\nunit3-console.exe"


## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Get all the Test dlls from the output directory 
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$tests = (Get-ChildItem $OutDir -Recurse -Include Demo.*Tests.dll)


## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Run all the tests and generate report in XML format
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

& $nunit --inprocess $tests --noheader --work="$OutDir"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a check on the Console runner exit code, as it returns total number of failures (the sum of failed, invalid or resulted in error tests, code is [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/blob/master/src/NUnitConsole/nunit3-console/ConsoleRunner.cs)).
To get the exit code in powershell just use `$LASTEXITCODE` (since you're running nunit in-process, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275960/find-exit-code-for-executing-a-cmd-command-through-powershell)).
Expect the following return codes from console runner:

- 0 - All tests passed
- Above 0 - Number of failures
- Below 0 - Error in Console runner: Invalid Assembly (-1), Argument (-2) or Fixture (-4) or unexpected error (-100)